Accessible result motivating Arithmetic Geometry
My understanding of arithmetic geometry is that it applies concepts originating from algebraic geometry to schemes that are quite different from these initially studied in this field (those associated to varieties over algebraically closed fields).
In particular, its objects of studies are schemes defined over $\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}}(\mathbb{Z})$.
When motivating this approach, the theorems that are generally mentioned are the Weil conjectures, Falting's theorem or even Fermat-Wiles theorem.
While all these results are beautiful and their statements are relatively easy to understand, their proofs are notoriously quite difficult.
Would you know a theorem in arithmetic geometry whose proof is relatively accessible (*) and highlights the importance of the concept of schemes in arithmetic?
(*) let's say it is not too long and it does not involve much concepts besides those studied in an introduction to modern algebraic geometry

This is probably still a little advanced for you, but I think that pp. 20-22 of https://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~vonkjb/publications/ICTS.pdf is very interesting in this respect.

In a less explicit but perhaps more elementary way, you could look at the behavior of the Galois action of a decomposition group at $p$ on the $p$-torsion of an elliptic curve, as in the first section of Serre’s ”open image” paper (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01405086).
